# using signal in multithread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, signals

I'm running following loops in multiple threads, in each thread, i need signal the thread to pass if it idles for 5 second.

```
for i in range(n):
    # do some network transferring work
```

But I found this in python documentation: 
Some care must be taken if both signals and threads are used in the same program. The fundamental thing to remember in using signals and threads simultaneously is: always perform signal() operations in the main thread of execution.

Since I shouldn't mix multi threads with signal, what other options I have to skip a loop if it idles for too long?

Comment: You can't generally interrupt a thread that's in the middle of doing something blocking. Python 3.3 makes it possible in some cases if you really know what you're doing and you don't care about Windows, but in general, this isn't the right solution.

Comment: If your "network transferring work" involves doing lots of little things where you get control back reasonably often, you can check a timer or a flag reasonably often. Or, if you're calling a function that has a timeout, or _could_ do so (e.g., replacing a `recvall` with a loop around `select` and `recv`), that's an easy solution. Butf it's just calling some function that can take 2 minutes and that has no `timeout` parameter, there's nothing you can do. So the answer is to not use threads—e.g., use child processes instead.